# Strange appearance of control M character

Tags: linux, unix, special-characters

I have a few scripts which generate some log files based on the output of some commands. The log files come in the following format (line numbers are not part of actual output),

```
1   cmd-0-start
2   <the_command>
3   <the_command_output>
4   <prompt>
5   cmd-0-end
```

Now, for some strange reason, the line containing the command (line 2) is getting split into 2 separate lines by control M character (`^M`). Due to this, a part of the actual command is spilling over to the line from where the **output** is supposed to start, i.e., line 3. Here's a sample

```
1   cmd-0-start
2   <the_^M
3   ^Mcommand>
4   <the_command_output>
5   <prompt>
6   cmd-0-end
```

This is causing havoc with my other scripts which parse the output, leading to incorrect analysis of the log. I know I can remove the special characters, but I would like to know **why** they are coming in the first place.

There are a few patterns I observed,

1. Its not occurring in all logs - only certain logs.

2. The affected logs have long commands.

3. The ^M appears exactly after the 69th character in each affected case!

Any ideas why this could be happening?

**EDIT:**

There is no interaction with any Windows system at all. Everything is running on Linux. So we can rule out mischief by Windows.

Comment: Yes, how would you want us to guess what creates this bogus character without having a clue about your scripts ?

Comment: do you get anything from `echo $COLUMNS`? good luck.

Comment: Sorry for the delay, had to discuss with the person who actually made the script for generating these outputs and understand the code. Its actually an expect script and uses the `\r` to insert a carriage return at the end of each `send`, which explains the ^M character. However, it's still unclear why the command is getting split over 2 lines - something to do with network lag? Also, $COLUMNS returns 80.

Answer (score 0):

You may have to run the file through dos2unix. See [man page here](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/oneiric/man1/dos2unix.1.html).

```
dos2unix infile
```

The reason why is that some windows system has written the file.

> In DOS/Windows text files a line break, also known as newline, is a
>          combination of two characters: a Carriage Return (CR) followed by a
>          Line Feed (LF). In Unix text files a line break is a single character:
>          the Line Feed (LF). In Mac text files, prior to Mac OS X, a line break
>          was single Carriage Return (CR) character. Nowadays Mac OS uses Unix
>          style (LF) line breaks.

Answer (score 0):

This happens because of the difference in the way a new line is defined in dos `(CR/LF)` as oposed to unix `(LF)`.
Use `dos2unix` to convert it to proper format